# Spring-boot application secured with a spring-boot OAuth2 server

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I am learning how to secure an application with Spring-boot and how to set up a OAuth2 server with this tutorial : [SSO with OAuth2: Angular JS and Spring Security Part V](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v). If I take the source from the [referenced Github account](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/oauth2), it works but does not fit my need.

Here is the architecture that I want ideally :

[image: Architecture]

**1)** A clear separation between frontend (pure html/js/css with angular & bootstrap) and backend thanks to a nginx redirection. Every request is received by nginx on port 80. Then, if it begins with /api, it is redirected to port 8080. Else, it is served as a static file by nginx.

Here is the corresponding nginx conf :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/adenoyelle/IdeaProjects/myapp/frontend;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location /api {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
 }
```

This part **works**.

**2)** Enable a login form instead of using the Basic Authentication dialog. As stated in the tutorial, I created a login form then I use this option on Angular's side to prevent the Basic Authentication dialog to appear :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

> The custom “X-Requested-With” is a conventional header sent by browser clients, and it used to be the default in Angular but they took it out in 1.3.0. Spring Security responds to it by not sending a “WWW-Authenticate” header in a 401 response, and thus the browser will not pop up an authentication dialog (which is desirable in our app since we want to control the authentication).

But it **does not work**, i.e. the Basic Authentication popup appears each time I try to access a protected resource or submit the login form!

In the chrome console, I can see the `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` in the request header and the `WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Spring"` header in the 401 response.

Here is the corresponding code on backend's side :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class Backend {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Backend.class, args);
  }

  @Configuration
  protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.logout().and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
          .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
          .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
      return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
          CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
              .getName());
          if (csrf != null) {
            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
            String token = csrf.getToken();
            if (cookie == null || token != null
                && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
              cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
              cookie.setPath("/");
              response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
          }
          filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
      };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
      HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
      repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
      return repository;
    }
  }

}
```

**3)** I expect the login request to be received by the Backend then, thanks to zuul, I expect it to be forwarded to the Authorization Server but maybe I misunderstood this part.

What actually happens : when I try to submit the login form, I see the Basic Authentication popup, I close it then I can see a trace on the backend server :

> 15:21:13.664 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener - AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Sep 04 15:21:13 CEST 2015, principal=user, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Bad credentials}]

and no traces on the Authorization server!

Here is the relevant part of the backend configuration :

```
spring.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
spring.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
spring.oauth2.client.client-id=acme
spring.oauth2.client.client-secret=acmesecret

zuul.routes.user.path=/user/**
zuul.routes.user.url=http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you got this thing working ? Please share your source code if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disable basic authentication

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.logout()
      .and()
      .httpBasic().disable()
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
      .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
      .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your issue has been resolved.

You are getting the browser pop-up because of spring authorisation on project Javascript file. If you check the tutorial part 7, it is mentioned that contents inside js/** folder are unsecured by default.

> Note: all the client-side code is under a single directory, “js” (except index.html because that is a “welcome” page and loads automatically from the “static” directory). This is intentional because it makes it easy to apply a single Spring Security access rule to all the static resources. These ones are all unsecured (because /js/** is unsecure by default in a Spring Boot application), but you might need other rules for other applications, in which case you would pick a different path.

If you put your files under js/** folder, the browser pop-up will not appear. Another way is to mentioned your folder in antmatchers under http configure method.

I hope this solves the issue.

Thanks.